# Google App Script Error : API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Not found: Job

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-workspace

I'm attempting to use Apps Script to retrieve data from BigQuery and put it to a spreadsheet, but I'm getting the following error notice when my script runs:

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Not found: Job project-id:jobxxxxxW`

this is my main script (change some line to dummy data) :

```
const projectId = 'project-id';

  const request = {
    // TODO (developer) - Replace query with yours
    query: 'SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE;',
    location: "region",
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  let queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  let jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  let sleepTimeMs = 1000;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  let rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken,
      location: request.location
      //location : bigQuerySettings.location
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
```

The script is failing here:

```
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
```

The case is the same with this : [API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Not found: Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842641/api-call-to-bigquery-jobs-getqueryresults-failed-with-error-not-found-job), but still couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100781/error-call-to-bigquery-jobs-get-fails-with-error-not-found?rq=2